# Compilar y solucionar el error JAVA

Tags: java, variables, operador

Me piden que se corrija el error de manera que se pueda ejecutar el código e indique donde se encuentra el mismo. No logro averiguar el error. Estoy trabajando con Netbeans, y no me apaño muy bien todavia. Agradezco de antemano la ayuda. Gracias.

```
public class Error {  
  public static void main(String[] name) {
    int x = 300;
    int y = 200;
    int z;
    int w = x + y + z;
    System.out.print(w);
  }
}
```

Comment: La variable Z no tiene ningún valor asociado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes inicializar la variable **z**, para inicializarlo se le da un valor, en este caso asigne 0 para inicializarla, a reserva de que desees darle otro.

```
public class Error {  
  public static void main(String[] name) {
    int x = 300;
    int y = 200;
    int z = 0;
    int w = x + y + z;
    System.out.print(w);
  }
}
```

Es importante tener en cuenta que las variables deben recibir un valor inicial antes de poder leer los datos que contienen. Si se trata de leer los datos del valor de una variable que no ha sido inicializada, los compiladores normalmente reportan un error y no compilan el programa.

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme a entender y a finalizar un ejercicio másYemisiSCG !! Que tengas una buena tarde!

Comment: De nada, si te sirvió te invito a que marques la respuesta como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de nuestro compañero es correcta si defines una variable dentro de un método en una clase de java, hay que instanciarla si o sí. también recalcar que si la variable es definida como atributo de la clase directamente, no es necesario instanciarla puesto que java instancia automáticamente las variables de clase, con lo que le hubiera dado un valor de 0 automáticamente por ser un int. Solo era como aclaración, ciertamente es una muy buena practica asignar valor a cualquier variable ya sea dentro de un método o de una variable de clase, para evitar fallos de este tipo por descuido.